# Window function trailing dates in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I am trying to write a query to compare the number of average connections today for a given computer to the number of average connections between 7 and 14 days ago. I figured this was best handled by a window function but I am not able to get the syntax correct for the date.

Assume I have a table of IP addresses and connection records called iptable with soucreip, destinationip, timestamp as the columns.  Here is the query I am trying for the previous 7 day window to just get the count per sourceip:

```
select 
  sourceip, 
  destinationip, 
  timestamp, 
  count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY sourceip order by timestamp
                 RANGE BETWEEN now() - '7 day'::Interval PRECEDING
                               now() - '14 day'::Interval FOLLOWING)
from
 iptable;
```

What is the best way to write this type of query does the window function approach make sense or is there a more optimized way to do things for the case of large tables?

Comment: Please show your PostgreSQL version in all questions, and the exact text of error messages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Part of your issue is that you've chosen a terrible column name, `"timestamp"`. `timestamp` is the name of a built-in data type, so to use it as a column name you must `"double quote"` it everywhere.

That's not all, though. Your window function syntax is wrong. See [window function syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS). You forgot the `AND`; it's `RANGE BETWEEN .. PRECEDING AND ... FOLLOWING`.

Also, though it isn't the cause of the issues, you should use the SQL-standard `current_timestamp` instead of `now()`.

That'll get you to a new error:

```
CREATE TABLE iptable ( sourceip cidr, destinationip cidr, "timestamp" timestamptz);

regress=> select 
  sourceip, 
  destinationip, 
  timestamp, 
  count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY sourceip order by "timestamp" RANGE BETWEEN current_timestamp - '7 day'::Interval PRECEDING AND current_timestamp - '14 day'::Interval FOLLOWING)

from
 iptable;
ERROR:  RANGE PRECEDING is only supported with UNBOUNDED
LINE 5: ... OVER (PARTITION BY sourceip order by "timestamp" RANGE BETW...
                                                             ^
```

which suggests that the current window function implementation won't do what you want it to do. Sadly.

> The value PRECEDING and value FOLLOWING cases are currently only
>   allowed in ROWS mode. They indicate that the frame starts or ends with
>   the row that many rows before or after the current row. value must be
>   an integer expression not containing any variables, aggregate
>   functions, or window functions.

Instead I'd just use a plain `GROUP BY` with a `WHERE` filter on the input rows.

```
select 
  sourceip,
  count(sourceip) AS n_conns_7_to_14_days_ago
from
 iptable
WHERE age("timestamp") BETWEEN INTERVAL '7' DAY AND INTERVAL '14' DAY
GROUP BY sourceip;
```

Answer (score 5):

To get ...

> the number of average connections between 7 and 14 days ago

```
SELECT sourceip, destinationip, timestamp, count(*) AS ct
FROM   iptable
WHERE  "timestamp" BETWEEN now() - '14 day'::interval
                   AND     now() -  '7 day'::interval
GROUP BY 1,2,3;
```

Just use a plain aggregate function.
And don't use `timestamp` as column name. It's a [protected word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in the SQL standard and partly reserved n PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

-- you can do it with filter

```
select 
  sourceip, 
  destinationip, 
  timestamp, 
  count(*) filter (where timestamp BETWEEN 
                  now() - '7 day'::Interval 
              and now() - '14 day'::Interval) 
           OVER (PARTITION BY sourceip order by timestamp)
from
 iptable;
```