# how to optimize a query which needs timestamp normalization

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following data source, which has several physical values (one per column) coming from several devices at different times:

```
+-----------+------------+---------+-------+
| id_device | timestamp  |  Vln1   | kWl1  |
+-----------+------------+---------+-------+
|       123 | 1495696500 |         |       |
|       122 | 1495696800 |         |       |
|       122 | 1495697100 | 230     | 5.748 |
|       122 | 1495697100 | 230     | 5.185 |
|       124 | 1495700100 | 226.119 | 0.294 |
|       122 | 1495713900 | 230     |       |
|       122 | 1495716000 |         |       |
|       122 | 1495716300 | 230     |       |
|       122 | 1495716300 |         |       |
|       122 | 1495716300 |         |       |
|       122 | 1495716600 | 230     | 4.606 |
|       122 | 1495716600 |         |       |
|       124 | 1495739100 |         |       |
|       123 | 1495739400 |         |       |
+-----------+------------+---------+-------+
```

`timestamp` is (unfortunately) `bigint` and each device sends data at different times and with different frequency: some of the devices push every 5 mins, others every 10mins, other every 15 mins. The physical values could be `NULL`.

A front-end application needs to plot charts - let us say line charts - of a specific time stamp, with time ticks every  minutes. Time ticks are chosen by the user.
The charts can be  made of multiple physical values of multiple devices, and each line is a independent request made to the backend.

Let us think about a case where:

1. the chosen time tick is 10 mins
2. two lines to plot are chosen, having two different physical values (columns) on two different devices:

   1. A device pushes every 5 mins
   2. The other every 10 mins

What the front-end app expects are normalized results:

```
<timestamp>, <value>
```

Where

1. `timestamp` represents rounded time (00:00, 00:10, 00:20, and so forth)
2. in case there are more than one `value` in each "timebox" (ex: there will be 2 values for a device pushing every 5 minutes within 00:00 and 00:10), a single value will be returned, which is an aggregated value (AVG)

In order to accomplish this I created some plpgsql functions that help me, but I'm not sure that what I'm doing is the best in terms of performance.

Basically what I do is:

1. Get the data for the particular device and phisical measure, within the timespan selected
2. Normalize the data returned: each timestamp is rounded to the time ticks selected (i.e. 10:12:23 -> 10:10:00). That way, each tuple will represent a value within a "time bucket"
3. Create a `range` of time buckets, according the chosen time ticks the user selected
4. `JOIN` the timestamp-normalized data with the range. Aggregate in case of multiple values within the same range

Here are my functions:

```sql
create  or replace function app_iso50k1.blkGetTimeSelParams(
      t_end bigint,
      t_granularity integer,
      t_span bigint,
  OUT delta_time_bucket interval,
  OUT b_timebox timestamp,
  OUT e_timebox timestamp)
as
$$
DECLARE
  delta_time interval;
BEGIN
  /* normalization: no minutes */
  t_end = extract('epoch' from date_trunc('minute', (to_timestamp(t_end) at time zone 'UTC')::timestamp));

  delta_time =  app_iso50k1.blkGetDeltaTimeBucket(t_end, t_granularity);
  e_timebox = date_trunc('minute', (to_timestamp(t_end - extract('epoch' from delta_time)) at time zone 'UTC'))::timestamp;
  b_timebox = (to_timestamp(extract('epoch' from e_timebox) - t_span) at time zone 'UTC')::timestamp;

  delta_time_bucket = delta_time;
END
$$ immutable language 'plpgsql' security invoker;


create or replace function app_iso50k1.getPhyMetData(
  tablename character varying,
  t_span bigint,
  t_end bigint,
  t_granularity integer,
  idinstrum integer,
  id_device integer,
  varname character varying,
  op character varying,
  page_size int,
  page int)
  RETURNS TABLE(times bigint , val double precision) as
$$
DECLARE
  series REFCURSOR;
  serie RECORD;
  first_notnull bool = false;
  prev_val double precision;
  time_params record;
  q_offset int;
BEGIN
  time_params = app_iso50k1.blkGetTimeSelParams(t_end, t_granularity, t_span);
  if(page = 1) then
    q_offset = 0;
  else
    q_offset = page_size * (page -1);
  end if;

  if not public.blkIftableexists('resgetphymetdata')
  THEN
    create temporary table resgetphymetdata (times bigint, val double precision);
  ELSE
    truncate table resgetphymetdata;
  END IF;

  execute format($ff$
  insert into resgetphymetdata (
    /* generate every possible range between these dates */
    with ranges as (
        select generate_series($1, $2, interval '$5 minutes') as range_start
    ),
      /* normalize your data to which <t_granularity>-minute interval it belongs to */
    rounded_hst as (
      select
        date_trunc ('minutes', (to_timestamp("timestamp") at time zone 'UTC')::timestamp)::timestamp -
        mod (extract ('minutes' from ((to_timestamp("timestamp") at time zone 'UTC')::timestamp))::int, $5) * interval '1 minute' as round_time,
        *
      from public.%I
      where
        idinstrum = $3 and
        id_device = $4 and
        timestamp <= $8
    )
    select
      extract('epoch' from r.range_start)::bigint AS times,
      %s (hd.%I) AS val
    from
      ranges r
      left join rounded_hst hd on r.range_start = hd.round_time
    group by
      r.range_start
    order by
      r.range_start
    LIMIT $6 OFFSET $7
  );
  $ff$, tablename, op, varname) using time_params.b_timebox, time_params.e_timebox, idinstrum, id_device, t_granularity, page_size, q_offset, t_end;

  /* data cleansing: val holes between not-null values are filled with the previous value */
  open series no scroll for select * from resgetphymetdata;
  loop
    fetch series into serie;
    exit when not found;

    if NOT first_notnull then
      if serie.val NOTNULL then
        first_notnull = true;
        prev_val = serie.val;
      end if;
    else
      if serie.val is NULL then
        update resgetphymetdata
        set val = prev_val
        where current of series;
      else
        prev_val = serie.val;
      end if;
    end if;
  end loop;
  close series;

  return query select * from resgetphymetdata;
END;
$$ volatile language 'plpgsql' security invoker;
```

Do you see good alternatives to what I coded? Is there room for improvements? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can fully translate your iterative logic with pure SQL query.
You can parametrize your query with a function.
For better performance use sql langage for your function.

You can build partial sum over timeseries interval using Window function like explained here
[Window function trailing dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368809/window-function-trailing-dates-in-postgresql)

Other suggestions

- Manage null values with coalesce
- Avoid timestamp conversion with a dedicated computed column
- You can use small computed views and join them in your final query or use LATERAL JOIN